# Spark job with magic s3 committer failed while processing .pendingset file inside _magic directory in the output path

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop

I am trying to use s3 magic committer in my spark job to write data on s3 bucket but it eventually failed while committing the file at the destination below is the error

Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadDigest; Request ID: 1689881089086345; S3 Extended Request ID: null; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1879)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1418)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1387)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5456)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5403)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.access$300(AmazonS3Client.java:421)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$PutObjectStrategy.invokeServiceCall(AmazonS3Client.java:6531)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1861)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1821)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.putObjectDirect(S3AFileSystem.java:2432)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.lambda$putObject$6(WriteOperationHelper.java:517)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:115)
... 15 more

I tried to commit data using s3 magic committer

Comment: can you stick up the full stack?

Comment: added stacktrace @stevel

Answer (score 0):

the calculated MD5 checksum of the upload (attached as a header to the PUT of the .pendingset JSON list of all files to commit for that task), doesn't match what AWS got.

I'd consider that some form of network problem, or HTTPS related.

now, the request ID is a simple number

```
Request ID: 1689881089086345; S3 Extended Request ID: null;
```

This is not an AWS S3 request ID, which is always a UUID. Which means you are using some third party store.

Talk to the authors of the s3 store. If this is replicable it'd be interesting to know whose store it is, even though the general view of the s3a codebase is *we don't go our our way to block 3rd party implementations, but do expect them to sort out their own compatibility issues*

See also: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html#SdkClientException_Unable_to_verify_integrity_of_data_upload